# Framed float environment containing title and body text and outer caption

Tags: floats, framed

I am writing in the `report` document class and am trying to reproduce the following result (from p. 20 of https://eprint.iacr.org/2016/505.pdf). [image: framed float environment containing title and body text and outer caption]

I want to produce a framed float containing a bold centered title and some arbitrary body text as well as a caption outside the frame. I have tried to use the figure environment along with the `framed` package, but the result is not exactly what I want.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{framed}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \begin{framed}
    \textbf{Title}
    \begin{description}
      \item[Foo] Body
      \item[Bar] content
    \end{description}
  \end{framed}
  \caption{A caption}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

produces the following result:
[image: test compilation result]

There is too much air between the bottom frame border and the text body. Furthermore, there is too much air between the bottom frame border and the caption.

Could any of you please suggest approaches that closer resemble the example I try to reproduce? Preferably as a custom environment where I can alter the caption label from "Figure" to something else.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Welcome to the TeX.SE. community.

Comment: @Sebastiano thank you!

Comment: Note that framed is very old and cannot do much. You might want to have a look at the `tcolorbox` package as it is a lot of cool features build in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```latex
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{float}
\floatstyle{boxed}
\newfloat{nonfigure}{tbp}{l0nfig}
\floatname{nonfigure}{Non Figure}
\begin{document}
\begin{nonfigure}
\centering
\textbf{Title}
\begin{description}
\item[Foo] Body
\item[Bar] content
\end{description}
\caption{A caption}
\end{nonfigure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is what I was looking for. Thank you.